# Read multiple files from S3 into PySpark dataframe

Tags: python, amazon-s3, pyspark

Let's say I have a couple of files in an S3 bucket, similar to this:

```
s3://data-raw-dev/GoogleAds/ad_group/cron_name=customer2/year=2024/month=02/googleads_ad_group_customer2_2024-02-20.parquet
s3://data-raw-dev/GoogleAds/ad_group/cron_name=customer2/year=2024/month=02/googleads_ad_group_customer2_2024-02-19.parquet
s3://data-raw-dev/GoogleAds/ad_group/cron_name=customer3/year=2024/month=02/googleads_ad_group_customer3_2024-02-20.parquet
s3://data-raw-dev/GoogleAds/ad_group/cron_name=customer3/year=2024/month=02/googleads_ad_group_customer3_2024-02-19.parquet
```

To read a single parquet file into a PySpark dataframe is fairly straight forward:

```
df_staging = spark.read.parquet(s3_path)
df_staging.show()
```

I need to read multiple files into a PySpark dataframe based on the date in the file name. So without having to loop through customer names and reading file by file, how can I read all of the files that has a date of 2024-02-19 in their names for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answers. I managed to get it working by using:
`s3://data-raw-dev/GoogleAds/ad_group/**/{year=2024/month=02}/*2_2024-02-19.parquet`

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to use a regex or glob:

The [syntax](https://books.google.com.vn/books?id=Wu_xeGdU4G8C&lpg=PA238&ots=i8wUUFRcZw&pg=PA65#v=onepage&q&f=false) includes:

- `*` (match 0 or more character)
- `?` (match single character)
- `[ab]` (character class)
- `[^ab]` (negated character class)
- `[a-b]` (character range)
- `{a,b}` (alternation)
- `\c` (escape character)

An example of usage is below, but would need to be tailored to your need:

```
spark.read.parquet("/user/Orders/2015072[7-9]*,/user/Orders/2015073[0-1]*")
```

Answer (score 0):

Check below.

```
WITH input_cte AS (
    SELECT * FROM `parquet`.`s3://data-raw-dev/GoogleAds/ad_group/`
    WHERE input_file_name() rlike '2024-02-19'
)
SELECT * FROM input_cte
```

```
spark.read.parquet("s3://data-raw-dev/GoogleAds/ad_group/")
.withColumn("file_name", input_file_name())
.filter(col("file_name").contains("2024-02-19"))
.select("file_name") -- Just to see what files it is loading.
.distinct()
.show(5, False)
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|file_name                                                                                                                    |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|s3://data-raw-dev/GoogleAds/ad_group/cron_name=customer2/year=2024/month=02/googleads_ad_group_customer2_2024-02-19.parquet  |
|s3://data-raw-dev/GoogleAds/ad_group/cron_name=customer2/year=2024/month=02/googleads_ad_group_customer3_2024-02-19.parquet  |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```